# User ID changed after uploading data on firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

After sign up authentication, it shows like that. For an example,

registration mail: test1@gmail.com
pass : 123456
UID : ABCFGAJAG55

But when I store data using current user UID , the UID changed.

[image: image -1]

[image: image - 2]

[image: code]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

If the upload is successful, the function will complete normally and return a Future. If there is an error, the catch block will catch the error and rethrow it so that the calling code can handle it.

```
Future<void> uploadData() async {
try {
  CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  ref.collection("users").doc(auth.currentUser?.uid).set(
    {
      "email": user.email,
      "name": user.displayName,
      "userId": user.uid,
      "profiledPhoto": user.photoURL ?? ""
    },
  );
} catch (e) {
  rethrow;
}
```

}

Comment: Catching an error just to rethrow it serves no purpose. Additionally, no error was mentioned in the question.